# Python datetime timedelta object with timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have a datetime timedelta object, which I parse from received UTC seconds like this which is an offset from todays midnight:

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
```

This is in UTC, but I want to add timezone awareness to it.

So for example now, the seconds=18600 reports 5:10:00 which is correct in UTC.

I want to add a fixed timezone to it, like 'Europe/Budapest', so it will show 6:10:00 or 7:10:00 (based on daytime-saving time).

Is it somehow possible if I don't have a full datetime object, only a timedelta?

Thanks!

Comment: What *exactly* do those seconds represent? A duration? An offset from… what? From today midnight UTC?

Comment: I have edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those seconds you get represent the offset since midnight UTC today (or any other particular day), then calculate them exactly as that:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
>>> import pytz

>>> midnight = datetime.now(timezone.utc).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 8, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

>>> timestamp = midnight + timedelta(seconds=seconds)
datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 8, 5, 10, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

>>> local_timestamp = timestamp.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Budapest'))
datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 8, 7, 10, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Budapest' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would like to offset the timedelta by the UTC offset?

```py
import datetime
import pytz

nowtz = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Europe/Budapest"))

seconds = 18600 + nowtz.utcoffset().total_seconds()
x = datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
```

```
>>> x
7:10:00
```

---

Or if you wanted a datetime

```
# This is a datetime object
>>> nowtz + x
datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 8, 21, 29, 2, 328802, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Budapest' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)

# This is the above datetime formatted as a string
>>> (nowtz+x).strftime("%F %r")
'2022-04-08 09:27:31 PM'
```

Comment: A `timedelta` is not conceptually what OP wants to end up with. They want to end up with a `datetime`, or perhaps just `time`.

Comment: `9:27 PM` is nowhere near the desired time though…

Comment: Thats the now time with a timezone, plus the time delta. I'm not sure what OP wants

Comment: *"6:10:00 or 7:10:00 (based on daytime-saving time)"*

Comment: Isn't that as a time delta ? what are the days, month and year ?

Comment: If it’s DST sensitive it’s not just a *duration* (`timedelta`), it’s a time of day. The day, month and year are supposedly implicitly today.